# Improve syntactic predicate error messages?

Tags: antlr

I am trying to improve the error messages antlr gives and noticed that syntactic predicates seem to be the root of the bad error messages.

This is the one I am currently working on. Here is an example of the grammar's structure. Sorry that I cannot provide the actual grammar. Hopefully this illustrates the point though.

```
defs
:   (a) => a | b
;


a
:   A B c
;

//b is actually much further down the chain and due to ordering can't be moved up.
b
:   A c
;
```

The issue is that for example if you have the tokens "A B D". The error message you get is from the 'b' rule. I want the error message to be from the 'a' rule. Meaning if "A B" is matched then I want an error if 'c' isn't matched.

I thought maybe you could do this

```
a
:   (A B) => A B c | {EmitErrorMessage("error");}
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should relax the syntactic predicate in `defs` instead of adding one to `a`.

```
defs
    :   (A B) => a
    |   b
    ;
```

This will cause the parser to choose the first alternative and enter the `a` rule based on just the two symbols `A B`.

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn I tried that earlier and it didn't work. Although I just tried that now and it works. Thanks!